# How do I access configuration options from within the app?

Tags: asp.net-core

What I tried:

HelloWorldController.cs

```
public class HelloWorldController : Controller
{
    public string Index()
    {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        // How do I do this?
        IConfiguration configuration = app.Configuration;
        List<String> list = configuration.options.ViewLocationExpanders;

        foreach(String item in list)
        {
            output.Append(HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode($"Looking in " + item));
        }

        return output.ToString();
    }
    ...
}
```

What I got: **Will not compile**

What I expected:

https://localhost:7127/HelloWorld

```
Looking in /Views/HelloWorld/Index.cshtml
Looking in /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
Looking in /Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject configuration into the constructor. The concept is called Dependency Injection (DI.)

All dependencies that the class needs are registered in `startup.cs` and then injected into the class through constructor.

```
[Route("")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private Configuration _configuration;

    public HomeController(IOptions<Configuration> configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration.Value;
    }
    [HttpGet, Route("Healthcheck")]
    public string Healthcheck()
    {
        return "Website is up. Version: " + _configuration.IMAGE_TAG ?? "Not available";
    }

}
```

In startup.cs, this is how the `Configuration` class is registered.

```
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DbEndpoints:DbConnectionString");

        services.Configure<Project.Server.Common.Configuration>(Configuration);
    }
```

Note that `Project.Server.Common.Configuration` is a regular class defined somewhere in the project that has the JSON configuration maps to (so it has the same structure as the `appsettings` JSON file.)

Example Configuration.cs

```
public class Configuration
{
    public string ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT { get; set; }
    public string IMAGE_TAG { get; set; }
    public DatabaseEndpoint DbEndpoints { get; set; }
}

public class DatabaseEndpoint
{
    public string DbConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

Note that you can also  access environment variables like `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` as long as you inject them as part of `startup.cs` constructor. (Note the `AddEnvironmentVariables` declaration below.

```
    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
            .AddJsonFile("staticsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false);

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

Comment: I don't have a startup.cs -- this is .Net Core 6 with C# 9

Comment: That doesn't really change anything. Instead of doing `new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")`, you'd do `builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")` and then `builder.Services.Configure<Configuration>(builder.Configuration)`. The builder object in program.cs exposes the same methods that I'm using above in old structure.

Comment: Considering that you want to use a Controller, you might as well check the "Do not use top level statements" when creating the project so that you get the "Controller" based dev experience.